# Corrupted partition - is SSD faulty?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

## Background

This morning when I turned my dual boot machine on and tried to enter Windows, it did not work. Window's self-diagnostic tool did not work and neither did `chkdsk` or `ntfsfix` both say the partition is beyond repair. Luckily I have most things backed up and Ubuntu still works (which is on the same drive). I don't know if this was caused by a Windows Update or the like, some environmental influence (I walked home in pouring rain with the Laptop in a cover in a water-proof backpack) or if the drive is faulty.

## Question

How can I assess if the SSD is faulty? It's an INTEL SSDPEKKW256G7 otherwise known as Intel SSD 600p Series (256GB). Intel has a [tool](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/de/download/28234/?product=94921) to assess the drive's health but it only runs on Windows.

## What I'Ve tried

`chkdsk` (which fails with `unable to determine volumen version and state`) and `ntfsfix` to try and fix the drive. I tried `smartctl` to figure out if it's worth to reinstall windows on the drive or buy a new one:

```
$ sudo smartctl -t long -a /dev/nvme0     
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-20-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       INTEL SSDPEKKW256G7
Serial Number:                      BTPY63520PCF256D
Firmware Version:                   PSF100C
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x8086
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x5cd2e4
Controller ID:                      1
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          256,060,514,304 [256 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Local Time is:                      Thu Nov  1 18:14:28 2018 GMT
Firmware Updates (0x12):            1 Slot, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0006):   Format Frmw_DL
Optional NVM Commands (0x001e):     Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         32 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     70 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     80 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     9.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        5       5
 1 +     4.60W       -        -    1  1  1  1       30      30
 2 +     3.80W       -        -    2  2  2  2       30      30
 3 -   0.0700W       -        -    3  3  3  3    10000     300
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4     2000   10000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02, NSID 0xffffffff)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        41 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    8%
Data Units Read:                    45,702,395 [23.3 TB]
Data Units Written:                 38,274,889 [19.5 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 1,028,294,677
Host Write Commands:                655,432,948
Controller Busy Time:               8,135
Power Cycles:                       2,208
Power On Hours:                     8,663
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   71
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    1
Error Information Log Entries:      316
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    24
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 64 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS
  0        316     4  0x005a  0x0004  0x018            0     1     -
  1        315     4  0x005a  0x0004  0x018            0     1     -
  2        314     4  0x005a  0x0004  0x018            0     1     -
  3        313     4  0x005a  0x0004  0x018            0     1     -
  4        312     4  0x005a  0x0004  0x018            0     1     -
  5        311     4  0x005a  0x0004  0x018            0     1     -
  6        310     4  0x005a  0x0004  0x018            0     1     -
  7        309     4  0x005a  0x0004  0x018            0     1     -
  8        308     4  0x005a  0x0004  0x018            0     1     -
  9        307     4  0x005a  0x0004  0x018            0     1     -
 10        306     4  0x005a  0x0004  0x018            0     1     -
 11        305     4  0x005a  0x0004  0x018            0     1     -
 12        304     4  0x005a  0x0004  0x018            0     1     -
 13        303     4  0x005a  0x0004  0x018            0     1     -
 14        302     4  0x005a  0x0004  0x018            0     1     -
 15        301     4  0x005a  0x0004  0x018            0     1     -
... (48 entries not shown)
```

I can see that SMART test is passed but I have trouble finding anything else that looks relevant.

Comment: Rather than run several individual commands on drive, run this as it shows lots of details. Please attach link to the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I had no luck installing the program but more importantly, it looks a bit beside the point to me, to be honest. I don't really care that much about repairing that partition. I'm rather worried that this might start to happen frequently and next time maybe in a more difficult situation. The question is thus how can I find out if I should better get a new drive?

Comment: If Smart Status says it is ok, that usually is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I just checked but the option is greyed out for that drive and Assessment is not displayed. A second traditional HDD can run the tests so I assume it's because of the NVMe standard.